# Weak law of large numbers ($\mathfrak{L^2}$-version)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of pairwise uncorrelated random variables out of $\mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{P}}^2$ on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ with
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{V}(X_i)=0.
$$
Show, that for all $\varepsilon >0$ it is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\left\lvert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E(X_i))\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)=0.
$$

Proof:

$X_n\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{P}}^2\Rightarrow X_n\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{P}}^1\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}(X_n)<\infty$.

Define 
$$
Y_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-E(X_i)).
$$

It is $Y_n\in\mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{P}}^2$, because
$$
\int_{\Omega}\left\lvert\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))\right\rvert^2\, d\mathbb{P}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\underbrace{\int_{\Omega}\lvert X_i\rvert^2\, d\mathbb{P}}_{<\infty}+\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(X_i)\right\rvert}_{<\infty}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\underbrace{\int_{\Omega}\lvert X_i\rvert\, d\mathbb{P}}_{<\infty}+\underbrace{\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(X_i)\right\rvert^2}_{<\infty}<\infty
$$
and as a linear combination of measurable functions, $Y_n$ is measurable.

Moreover, it is
$$
\mathbb{V}(Y_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))\right)\\=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Cov}(X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i),X_j-\mathbb{E}(X_j))\\=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\\=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)\\=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{V}(X_i),
$$
whereat the last identity is ok, because the $X_n$ are pairwise uncorrelated.

Furthermore, it is
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(E(X_i)-\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_i)))\\=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbb{E}(X_i)-\mathbb{E}(X_i))=0.
$$

All in all, one can apply Tschebyschev: For any $\varepsilon >0$ it is
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\lvert Y_n\rvert>\varepsilon\right\}\right)\leq\frac{\mathbb{V}(Y_n)}{\varepsilon^2}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{V}(X_i)\to 0~\Box
$$

*Can you save me, if my proof is right?*